# Cakephp 2 update multiple records

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.0

i'm newbie in cakephp and i trying to update multiple rows in one transaction like:

```
$Model->saveMany($data, array('deep' => true));
```

... And the structure of the **$data** array is:

```
$data = array(
  (int) 1 => array( 'Item' => array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Name 1') ),
  (int) 2 => array( 'Item' => array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Name 2') ),
);
```

I Already tried with **saveAll** instruction and without **deep** parameter but nothing :( .... what's wrong?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: is id primary key of the table ?

Comment: Yes! id is primary key (and unique) of the table

Comment: okey your array format is all good,nothing wrong with that..is that showing some error ??

Comment: is items name of the table you are updating ?

Comment: I looked the debug.log and error.log file at the project and nothing.

Comment: no, are more items ... the **name** field is only a example
But in the validation of the model  i have nothing required for this :/

Comment: what is the name of the table you are updating ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that it had a required field in the validation that, although it was not compromised in the update, anyway it had to be passed in command

Thank you all!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this following code to insert data in Cake Php,

```
$this->request->data = Hash::insert($this->request->data);
```

Comment: But that is for insert data in array not in the database model